# How to access Amazon images with https (AWSECommerceService)

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-product-api

For each product on my website I have a page that promotes a few book from Amazon. I get the books using a query to `AWSECommerceService` from my web server. The XML I receive from Amazon contains a list of books with information such as title, price, image-url, etc. I use those info to generate my website page.
The images URLs provided by Amazon are all `HTTP`, while I need to publish them using an the `HTTPS` protocol in order to avoid warnings for the page visitors at the browser lever. Just replacing `HTTP` with `HTTPS` doesn't work.

Example:

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51tD0SDNMeL.SX166.jpg => OK

https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51tD0SDNMeL.SX166.jpg => ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

I just found out that the same images can be accessed via HTTPS on a different amazon.com sub-domain:

Replacing '`http://ecx.images-amazon.com`' with '`https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com`' will generate a perfectly working URL.

The image in the example in my question can be successfully accessed via `https` at the following URL:

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51tD0SDNMeL.SX166.jpg